# php max function to get name of highest value?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multi array and I am using the max function to return the highest value, however I'd like it to return the name?  How can I do that?

```
$total = array($total_one => 'Total One', $total_two => 'Total Two');
echo max(array_keys($total));
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `$total_one` and `$total_two`?

Comment: Please add az complete output of how your array looks like

Answer (score 2):

First off, I think you have your keys and values reversed in your array. But nonetheless, you can do something like this:

```
echo $total[max(array_keys($total))]
```